# Twitter API Search

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I want to search for tweets referencing @WWE account. I followed this documentation to do the same:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

This is the URL I get after following their instructions: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=WWE&src=typd

But instead of getting the JSON equivalent, this is what I am getting:

{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to authenticate with api 1.1.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth

Comment: Okay, can you be a little more elaborative? I get that want I want is a Search API. But I'm not sure whether I want to send a OAuth signed or application-only auth request. All this is really complex for me.